# local block with ObjC and ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Block_copy recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420656/is-block-copy-recursive)

I'm not sure how block retain a block works.

```
int i = 0;
void(^stackBlock)(void) = ^(void) {
    (void)i;  //use local variable 'i'
};
NSLog(@"%@", stackBlock);

void(^completionHandler)(void) = ^(void) {
    stackBlock();
};
[something doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
```

stackBlock is a `__NSStackBlock__` which means retain it is useless.
`doSomethingWithCompletionHandle:` will copy the completionHandler and invoke it later after some data is downloaded from internet.

My question is that is the example code safe?

Because I know retain `__NSStackBlock__` is useless so `stackBlock` will not be retained (copy should be used instead) then invoke it outside the scope is not safe.